# Return n-th row from a csv-file by batch

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a csv-file like:

```
id, col1, col2
1, a, b
2, c, d
3, e, f
```

So my question is: how can I get the second row (for example) by using a batch-file? I need to check if something went wrong in my R import. The file is way too big to search the line I need by text editor.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what language are you using bash? cmd.exe? Powershell?

Comment: I am thankful for every solution that I can use on windows. Commands for .bat or .cmd would be great. I cannot install new software to use the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Bash, use sed to print line 42

```
sed -n '42p' myfile.csv
```

Comment: I could use this command in the installed GitBash. Works fine for me. Thanks for your fast response.

Answer (score 2):

Despite there already being an accepted answer, here's a crazy looking answer using a batch-file, **as tagged**:

```bat
@More +162 myfile.csv|FindStr/N $|Findstr/B 1:|(Pause>Nul&Pause>Nul&Findstr $)
@(Timeout -1)>Nul
```

Replace `162` if you don't want to display line 163, *(the number should be your wanted line number minus one)*.

Answer (score 0):

If you can start `powershell` from cmd.exe you can use this:

```
(Get-Content file.csv)[42]
```

Answer (score 0):

in windows cmd.exe shell you can use `more` to start displaying the file at line 42

```
more +42 myfile.csv
```